# How we can define a constant swiftUI-Type Font in SwiftUI?

Tags: swiftui

I can define a constant Font in UIKIt with this code:

```
let appFont = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 18, weight: UIFont.Weight.regular)
```

And as you know we can use fonts in SwiftUI like this:

```
.font(.system(size: 35, weight: .ultraLight, design: .rounded))
```

now I like to make a constant of this code as appFont and call this code with just using .appFont, how we can do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I correctly understood your needs, this can be done by extension to View, like

```
extension View {
    func appFont() -> some View {
        self.font(.system(size: 35, weight: .ultraLight, design: .rounded))
    }
}
```

so anywhere in your views you can use it as

```
var body: some view {
   SomeView().appFont()
}
```

Comment: I'm sure this is what the OP meant, but it's not actually constant, right? Can't the results of `.system()` change based on the environment?

Answer (score 2):

You can declare your `Font` in an extension:

```
extension Font {

    static let appFont = Font.system(size: 18, weight: .regular)
}
```

and then use it like this:

```
Text("Example")
    .font(.appFont)
```